# Error: "firebase.appCheck(app)" arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I am working on a React-native Android app. When I try to set up Phone authentication with Firebase with Firebase App check attestation with play integrity API, I am getting the above-mentioned error.

Here is my index.js file.

[image: Index.js]

this is App.tsx

[image: App.tsx]

And the error I am getting.

[image: Error]

Also, is there any other way other than play integrity to do app attestation in android react native?